# Use the Squeeze Theorem to prove the sequence $\frac{(-1)^{n}n}{n^3+1}$ converges to 0?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

The sequence is:
$$a_{n} := \frac{(-1)^{n}n}{n^3+1}$$
Do I start by dividing numerator and denominator by $n^3$?

Comment: I'd start by showing absolute value of your expression goes to zero. Then squeeze applied via $-|x|\le x \le +|x|.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $|a_n| \le \dfrac{n}{n^3+1}\le \dfrac{1}{n^2}< \dfrac{1}{n}$

Answer (score 0):

You can also prove it converges to zero according to $\varepsilon-n_{\varepsilon}$ definition.

Indeed, based on the answer of @WangYeFei, let $n\geq n_{\varepsilon}$.

Then it results that
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{(-1)^{n}n}{n^{3} + 1} - 0\right| & = \frac{n}{n^{3}+1} \leq \frac{n}{n^{3}} = \frac{1}{n^{2}} \leq \frac{1}{n^{2}_{\varepsilon}}
\end{align*}

Thus we conclude that
\begin{align*}
(\forall\varepsilon >0)(\exists n_{\varepsilon} = \lceil 1/\sqrt{\varepsilon}\rceil)(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})\left(n\geq n_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow \left|\frac{(-1)^{n}n}{n^{3} + 1} - 0\right| < \varepsilon\right)
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps !

Comment: yes that really helps. thank you!

Comment: @amy You can upvote/choose my answer if you think it deserves.